# How to let know the parent form that the child form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms

My main form opens child form. When the child form closes the parent form needs to perform some tasks. How the parent can know that the child form was closed.

I have a workaround - the hidden button and I invoke PerformeClick method when the child raises the closing event.

Is there any better (more correct) way of doing it?

Comment: Have you looked at the form closed event?

Comment: Please post your current code. How are you opening up the child form? Is it a modal dialog? Do you want it to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a listener event for your main/parent form when you instantiate child form. Example below:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.CustomFormClosed += CloseListener;
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void CloseListener(object sender, EventArgs e, string test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
```

Edited for Custom Delegates & Events

Form2 code:

```
    public delegate void CustomFormClosedHandler(object semder, FormClosedEventArgs e, string text);
    public event CustomFormClosedHandler CustomFormClosed;

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomFormClosed(sender, e, "Hello World!");
    }
```

Comment: Thx. Can I pass any parameter?

Comment: @P__J__ It can but you can't use the built in FormClosed event as its delegate has its own specific parameters. You'd have to register a new Delegate and Event in order to use parameters.

Comment: @P__J__ I'm assuming the parameter is a data from the child form. Correct?

Comment: @Mrs_N_C can you elaborate on that? That code should be working as I've just copied and pasted it from the IDE myself.

Comment: @Mrs_N_C yes, as I've coded and tried that myself in Visual Studio.

Comment: I figured it out. The `CloseListener` event is fired. But the message `"Form2 is closed"` never showed up for me. I guess this is the thread related problem.

Comment: @Boxed - yes from the child form. Of course I am looking for the "canonical" form without workarounds :)

Comment: @P__J__ I've updated my answer for passing values from child form.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is:

return `DialogResult` from `FormClosing` event handler of `Form2`

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Run modal `ShowDialog()` on a new thread from `Form1` and wait for the `DialogResult`

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // do here whatever you want to do
            MessageBox.Show("Form2 closed");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see the need for the method `Form2_FormClosing` in the above code.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What do you suggest then? Where should I set the `DialogResult`?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do:

1: Add public static method in the parent form:

```
public static void ChildFromClosed()
    {
        //Inform here
        MessageBox.Show("Child form is closed!");
    }
```

2: Add a (FormClosed) event in the child form that calls that method from the parent form:

```
private void frmChild_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //calling the static method in Parents form
        frmParent.ChildFromClosed();
    }
```